# How to load enum to MVC4 model from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

```
public enum UserGender: byte {
    Unknown = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UserGender Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

DDL script for the MSSQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE UserProfile(
    UserId   int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserName nvarchar(56) NOT NULL,
    Email    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Gender   tinyint NOT NULL,
    Address  nvarchar(1000) NULL
)
```

All the fields are being loaded from database as they should except `Gender`. It is always populated with 0. There is an obvious typecast failure although the enum is derived from `byte` type.

How to load enum the right way and keep it as enum in model?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? Enum is very well supported in latest version, however it was issue with previous version. Have you  tried removing `byte` from enum defination

Comment: @Satpal: I am not sure but think that 4.4.0.0, runtime version v4.0.30319

Comment: your db and c# type should match, change it to ``int`` instead of ``byte``

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: Ok, I'll try, but isn't `tinyint` an equivalent to `byte` ? Both are 8 bit and both are unsigned.

Comment: If I am not wrong enum's are not supported in 4.x version

Comment: @Satpal: Sad because I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You can create a property which stores the data in int. In short an underlying property from which non mapped gender property read/write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe newer version of EF support it pretty well,so I'm assuming you're using an older version of EF. Not the most elegant solution, but for older versions, you can do something like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int GenderID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual UserGender Gender 
    {
        get
        {
             return (UserGender)GenderID;
        }
        set
        {
             GenderID = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```